# Pandas.cut() on categorical values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['A+', 'A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'C+', 'C', 'C-', 'D+', 'D'],
                  index=['excellent', 'excellent', 'excellent', 'good', 'good', 'good', 'ok', 'ok' , 
                         'ok', 'poor', 'poor'])
df.rename(columns={0: 'Grades'}, inplace=True)
df= df.iloc[::-1]
dataframe.Grades = pd.Categorical(dataframe.Grades, 
               categories = list(dataframe.Grades),
               ordered = True)
```

but then i want to use pd.cut to divide the values in two bins

```
pd.cut(df.Grades, 2, labels=['Good', 'Bad'])
```

but it returns an error that says

> can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

What is my mistake? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Pandas cut is not the right tool. It transforms a continuous variable into a binned variable. Example :

```
values = pd.Series([0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
binned = pd.cut(values, bins=3)

binned
>>>  0  (-0.006, 2.0]
     1  (-0.006, 2.0]
     2  (-0.006, 2.0]
     3  (2.0, 4.0]
     4  (2.0, 4.0]
     5  (4.0, 6.0]
     6  (4.0, 6.0]
```

As you can see it determined bins (3 bins of 2 units to cover the 0-6 range) and it converted the continuous values to categorical by assigning the corresponding bin.

If you want further help, please edit your question, give your input and desired output so we can understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering how pandas.cut works. I was trying to split the series into 2 categories